# Chrome does not return a handle when used as a window in the winwait functions of autoit(Also chrome udf functions dont work)

Tags: autoit

```
#Include <Chrome.au3>

_ChromeShutdown()
_ChromeStartup("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en-gb&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
$result = WinWait("[CLASS:Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND]", "", 6)
Sleep(3000)
ConsoleWrite($result)
Send("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
Send("{Enter}")

**RETURN = 0**
```

Comment: Where did you took this: `Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND`information from?

Comment: I took that from the autoit window info tool...btw dude, i replaced the class to title and it worked